# Undefined control sequence when converting from conference to thesis

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to put this (previously working in ACM MM conference paper) into my thesis. I am not sure how to fix this error:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
   \subfloat[ \label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/nonfood/1798839913309241231.jpg}}
\hspace{.5em}
   \subfloat[\label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/nonfood/1802196180958251139_1.jpg}}
\hspace{.5em}
   \subfloat[\label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/nonfood/1779651030105353949.jpg}}
\hspace{.5em} 
    \subfloat[\label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/nonfood/1778498672250657472_8.jpg}}\\
\vspace*{-.3cm}
      \subfloat[ \label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/food/1979635016158043221.jpg}}
\hspace{.5em}
   \subfloat[ \label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/food/1719645603783530760.jpg}}
\hspace{.5em}
   \subfloat[ \label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/food/1705109660573689268_2.jpg}}
\hspace{.5em}
    \subfloat[\label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{figures/food/1689999632951126918_2.jpg}}
      \vspace*{-0.3cm}
\caption{Images correctly classified by KenyanFC but misclassified by ResNeXt101 when trained on FCD and tested on our Kenya104K. Images in the first row are non-food images misclassified as food images; images in the second row are food images misclassified as non-food images.}
    \label{fig:fnf_failure}
        \vspace*{-0.2cm}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

images are shown as below:

[image]

While they should show as:

[image]

Here's the link to published paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3347448.3357170

Please note my thesis is one column and the conference paper is double-columned.

Comment: Please, can you put the whole code starting from \documentclass? What package do you use?

Answer (score 5):

The [`subfig` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subfig) is missing from your preamble. However, if the intent is that the output is just an array of pictures without showing any numbering for the separate images, then you can just use `tabular` structure inside your `figure`. The use of `\label` has no meaning as there's no numbering to reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image-b} &
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image-c}
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image-c} &
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image-b} &
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[width=1.8cm, height=1.8cm]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Images correctly classified by KenyanFC but misclassified by ResNeXt101 when trained 
  on FCD and tested on our Kenya104K. Images in the first row are non-food images misclassified 
  as food images; images in the second row are food images misclassified as non-food images.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The spacing between rows and columns can be adjusted as needed.

Comment: But your test images are bigger than mine? ahahahahh

Comment: @Sebastiano: C-B-A-C-B-B-C-C :)

Comment: LOL :-) It is a secret code to decrypt....

Comment: Simple and effective (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? (I am without a MWE and of your images): Try it. If you want decrease the spaces between the figures look the value of `\hspace{1em}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-b}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-a}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-c}} 

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-b}}\hspace{1em}   
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-b}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}\hspace{1em} 
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm]{example-image-c}}

\caption{Images correctly classified by KenyanFC but misclassified by ResNeXt101 when trained on FCD and tested on our Kenya104K. Images in the first row are non-food images misclassified as food images; images in the second row are food images misclassified as non-food images.}
\label{fig:fnf_failure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As supplement to @Sebastiano answer (+1) ...

You can also use the `subcaption` package version 1.3 (or newest) and keys `Gin` for shorter figure code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=1.8cm,height=1.8cm}
    \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}\hspace{1em}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}

\caption{Images correctly classified by KenyanFC but misclassified by ResNeXt101 when trained on FCD and tested on our Kenya104K. Images in the first row are non-food images misclassified as food images; images in the second row are food images misclassified as non-food images.}
\label{fig:fnf_failure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the mention of my name. A simple curiosity: hence with the \setkeys{Gin} can you set the size of the figure without put width=1.8cm and height=1.8cm every time? +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, yes. This is special handy when all images has the same size (as in this case). Anyway, you can anytime locally overwrite this settings.